# Understanding the behavior of the trace in calculating the gradient

Tags: matrix-equations, machine-learning, trace

In Andrew Ng's notes in Machine Learning, I found this equality that I don't understand why it's true.
$$∇_θJ(θ) = (1/2) ∇_θ (θ^TX^T Xθ − θ^T X^T y − y^TXθ + y^T y)$$
$$ = (1/2) ∇_θ tr(θ^TX^T Xθ − θ^T X^T y − y^TXθ + y^T y)$$
$X, θ,$ and $y$ have the following dimensions.$$X \in R^{m \times n},  θ \in R^{n},  y \in R^{m}$$

He doesn't mention why this steps is true, so I wonder why this is true. Can anyone help? Thanks!

(The full development of the equation is in page 11 on http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf)

Comment: The quantity inside the trace is a real number / scalar, so it's trace is equal to itself.

Comment: @elexhobby: Your comment is an answer; would you mind reposting it as an Answer, to remove this question from the unanswered list?

Comment: "He doesn't mention why this steps is true..." The explanation is right below the equation: "In the third step, we used the fact that the trace of a real number is just the real number".

Answer (score 1):

The quantity inside the trace is a real number / scalar, so its trace is equal to itself.